# Satmar before 1905

Tags: minhag, chasidut-hasidism, nusach-sefard, satmar

What did the Kehillas Satu Mare (Satmar) have in terms of minhagim, nusach, etc. before R' Yoel ben R' Chananiah-Yom-Tov-Lipa Teittelbaum founded the Satmar Hasidic Sect/Dynasty?

Comment: I would assume something close to regular Hungarian minhogim?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satu_Mare#Jewish_community the references here might be useful